Sharing a serial port between periodic background task and user button click actions
I'm writing a simple C# winforms GUI to control some lab equipment. My GUI has several buttons and labels used to display information received via serial polling as well as allow the user to send commands to the equipment. Both the commands to the equipment and the answers back vary in size depending on the state the machine is in and which command is being sent/answered. As of now I have it functional via a Windows.Forms.Timer callback and implementing what I think is primitive device deconfliction in the primary thread, but it makes the GUI laggy (unresponsive while performing the update I assume). Most users of this GUI will be okay with this, but in the past I've had colleagues who start clicking like they're in a Starcraft tournament when a GUI shows the slightest bit of a hiccup. It gets the job done, but I'd like to learn how to do it better. I've spent about a week reading stuff here, on MSDN, GFG, etc and I see a lot of stuff that seems relevant but it flies just a bit over my head and I'm having trouble stitching it together and I'm hoping you guys/gals can help.
Right now I'm deconflicting my serial port using a couple booleans. My development is happening on an unconnected machine, but here's a relevant framework for what I'm doing.

class MyCoolGadget
{
   private bool updateInProgress;
   private bool commandInProgress;
   private System.Windows.Forms.Timer updateTimer = new System.Windows.Forms.Timer();

   public MyCoolGadget()
   {
      updateTimer.Interval = 1000;
      updateTimer.Tick += new EventHandler(updateCallback);
      updateInProgress = false;
      commandInProgress = false;
      // Other constructor stuff
   }

   private void updateCallback(object sender, EventArgs e)
   {
      Update();
   }

   // This method is called by other class methods as well as by GUI element callbacks
   public byte[] sendCommand(byte id, byte[] payload) 
   {
      string caller = new System.Diagnostics.StackFrame(1).GetMethod().Name;

      // Loop here checks to see if there is an update is in progress and it needs to wait
      // for the serial port. If Update is the caller, we ignore the wait or we get stuck 
      // in an infinite loop. This is part of what i want to clean up.
      while (updateInProgress && (caller != "Update"))
      {
         Thread.Sleep(25);
      }

      if (caller != "Update")
      {
         commandInProgress = true;
      }

      // Build message, send it, get answer

      if (caller != "Update")
      {
         commandInProgress = false;
      }

      return answer;
   }

   // This method is called every second by the timer's callback
   private void Update()
   {
      byte[] replyBuffer;

      while (commandInProgress)
      {
         Thread.Sleep(10);
      }

      updateInProgress = true;

      replyBuffer = sendCommand(id1, payload1);
      // Update properties based on reply. GUI elements bound to class properties so they update
      // without further action on my part.

      replyBuffer = sendCommand(id2, payload2);
      // Update properties based on reply.

      replyBuffer = sendCommand(id3, payload3);
      // Update properties based on reply.

      updateInProgress = false;
   }
}

So this works, but it's clunky, causes GUI lag, and I'm sure is not the best way to handle it. I've seen several articles and answers that appear to have elements of my issue, but when I try to adapt those solutions I end up either breaking my code altogether or getting behavior I neither expect nor understand.
My end goal is that the Update method is being called on a background thread so the GUI doesn't appear to stutter and when a user action prompts that a message be sent (a button click in most cases) that message doesn't overlap the Update. I'm pretty sure that async methods and await will come into play, but when I try to use them I get errors and I haven't found examples that I'm able to understand. I've also looked into delegates, but the examples I see just look like using a method to call a method and I don't see how that moves anything to the background. Examples with explanations tailored to a hardware person would be welcome.
Thank you in advance!

Sounds like you should put the commands onto a BlockingCollection and have another thread/task pull them off and execute in order.

You already have a "timer" interval (loop); to add "sleeps" to that makes little sense since you can do whatever you need to do on the next iteration which is already "short" enough (1 sec). You can even make it shorter. The serial port "pattern" in this case is just looking for new data. If it's not there, you exit the current interval. If there is data, you read until you're done ... insuring you "skip" any new timer event if you're "busy". And you're only "expecting" data if you sent a request in the first place, and it hasn't "timed out".
